# How to remove query part from $request->all() in Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my project, I use `$request->all()` to get params.

But `$request->all()` includes query thing. When I post a `name => 1` to my API `'domain.com/api/users'`

`var_dump $request->all()`

example :

```
[
    'api/users' => null,
    'name'   => 1,    
]
```

I want to remove like `'api/users'` in my every `$request->all()`. What should I do?

Comment: can you show your controller code and the dd of $request->all();

Comment: what laravel version are you using?

Comment: Use validate method to prevent this, but how it is possible that you are getting segment in `$request`, is it really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot guarantee that I perfectly understood the question but based on my understanding, to filter out fields that are not sent as part of the request, then using `request()->only(['field', 'field_2'])` should be sufficient given the instance stated in [L5.5 upgrade notice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) about `request->only` method:

[image]

It means given the example I have, if `field_2` is not present in the request, then it is discarded.

If you are on Laravel **BEFORE** 5.5 then `$request->all()` will give you only existing field, else for L5.5 you use `request->only()` You can give it a try and see how they work.

**ON Laravel <= 5.4 and also L5.5**

Finally, if you still get those fields as null then you can simply use `array_filter($request_array)` e.g:

```
    $request_only = $request->all();
    $requests_without_null_fields =  array_filter($request_only);
```

This will remove all fields that are null preserving only fields that are not null.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: thinks for your replay,unfortunately,I use laravel 5.4., I change laravel 'vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\Inter‌​actsWithInput.php' file, 'input' function ,remove '+ $this->query->all()' in return ,can solve my question ,but I can't know What impact in project,do you know?

Comment: yes, in case there are other parts of the project that requires that then something might break. Its also **NOT** recommended to changed vendor packages since when you run composer update they would/might be affected and also when you move to a different environment/server

Comment: My answer stated a solution also for Laravel 5.4 simply use `array_filter()` on the request array i.e either `$request->all()` or `request->only(['field'])` after this you will get only values that are not null.

Comment: think you , best wishes for you

Answer (score 3):

You can use "except" or "only" method to filter your requests data.

```
$data = $request->except('key-that-you-dont-want-in-request');
// OR
$data = $request->only(['key-that-you-want-in-request', 'another-key']);
```

you can learn more about it here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: $request->except('query') not working,thanks your reply

Comment: it won't work if you put query inside the except. can you show me the output of dd($request->all());

Comment: [
    'api/users' => null,
    'name'   => 1,    
]                                                 in different api ,this 'api/users' is change, is not accurate key,so i don't know how to except it

Comment: did you try $request->except('api/users') ? what do you mean by change?

Comment: i try it ,but not working . 'change' is when i invole api 'domain.com/aa/bb', post params is [ 'aa/bb' => null],Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 5.5 you can also do it like this:

```
$data = $request->except(array_keys($request->query()));
```

Because `$request->query()` returns an array of only the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all the request parameters being passed into one variable something like this:

```
$data = $request->only(['name', 'other_request_variables']);
```

An then use it as required.

**Edit:**

When you try to update the model, and you have need to pass all the variable from the views i.e. even if the old data is not updated with the new one you need to pass all the data from the form,

and in controller you can do something like this:

```
$user = User::find($request->id);
```

Get all the data and send back to views in the form and while sending the form data you need to send all the data:

```
$data = $request->(['id', 'name', 'city', 'address']);
$user = User::find($data['id']);
$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->city= $data['city'];
$user->address = $data['address'];
$user->save();
```

If you do not pass the old data then above code will update with the `null` values of the same.

And suppose you don't want to update with null values then you don't have to call it, suppose you call only name and id then just simply write:

```
$data = $request->(['id', 'name', 'city', 'address']);
$user = User::find($data['id']);
$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->save();
```

So in this case your `city` and  `address` will be same with the old data, but in front end you don't know end user is updating what values, it can be either `name`, `city` or `address` you have to give flexibility to the end user.

Suppose you want to check the null values and then store it you can do something like this:

```
$data = $request->(['id', 'name', 'city', 'address']);
$user = User::find($data['id']);
$user->name = $data['name']: $data['name'] ? $user->name;
$user->city= $data['city'] : $data['city'] ? $user->city;
$user->address = $data['address'] : $data['address'] ? $user->address;
$user->save();
```

But in this case also you have to update with all parameters.

Comment: in my update userInfo function , The number of parameters is not fixed，because user can update section fields, how i can do it?

Comment: if I only post 'id','name'  ，In your function,'city' and 'address' will be setted null,I think It's not a good way to update in my project

Comment: I've updated my answer with explanation why it is required.

Comment: have you considered validation and ensuring any of those fields are not null, so you don't have to go through monitoring everything by yourself?

Comment: it means every time in update function,i will filter params null,do you have better way to deal it ?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi I've updated the answer, are you talking about the same which I've updated?

Comment: thinks for your replay, I  change laravel 'vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput.php' file, 'input' function ,remove '+ $this->query->all()' in return ,can solve my question ,but I can't know What impact in project,do you know?

Comment: Whenever you will do composer update to update your repository it will be over written, moreover this is bad practice which you have implemented.

Comment: While adding to `git` you do not share your `vendors` folder and you can see during `laravel` installation you get a `gitignore` file where `vendors` folder is skipped so further any of your friends or team mates are using the code they will do `git clone` of your repo and then `composer install`, which again will give them codes which are not edited by you.